# Echo class depending on Parent category

Tags: categories

What im trying to do is echo a class depending on witch of 3 Main "Parent" Categories the content was posted in , here is my code so far

```
<article class="post 
<?php 
if ( in_category( 'dream-it' )){ echo 'dreamit'; } 
if ( in_category( 'build-it' )){ echo 'buildit'; }
if ( in_category( 'get-the-hell-out' )){ echo 'getout'; } 
?>
">
```

I know im doing this wrong any help would be amazing ! thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you probably need to get the parent category of each of the post's categories first.

```
<?php
$parent_cat = array();
$post_cats = get_the_category($post->ID);
  foreach( $post_cats as $post_cat ) {
  if( $post_cat->parent ) $parent_cat[] = get_category( $post_cat->parent )->slug;
  }
?>
<article class="post  <?php  
  if ( in_array( 'dream-it', $parent_cat ) ) { echo ' dreamit'; }  
  if ( in_array( 'build-it', $parent_cat ) ) { echo ' buildit'; } 
  if ( in_array( 'get-the-hell-out', $parent_cat ) ) { echo ' getout'; }  ?> ">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `post_class()` function for that, like so:

```
<article <?php post_class(); ?>>
```

for more information check functions codex page - http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_class

**Update**

Put following code in your functions.php

```
add_filter( 'post_class', 'mamaduka_add_parent_category_class' );
/**
 * Add parent category class to post_class() function
 *
 */
function mamaduka_add_parent_category_class( $classes ) {
    global $post;

    foreach ( (array) get_the_category( $post->ID ) as $cat ) {
        if ( ! empty( $cat->parent ) ) {
            $parent_cat = &get_category( $cat->parent );
            $classes[] = 'category-parent-' . sanitize_html_class( $parent_cat->slug, $parent_cat->term_id );
        } else {
            $classes[] = 'category-parent-' . sanitize_html_class( $cat->slug, $cat->term_id );
        }
    }
    return $classes;
}
```

Comment: Cool thanks for the response! I might not be quite understanding this method so far, but it does not seem to work for me. All my posts are in sub-categories of the main parent, and im trying get the the div to change a class depending on witch parent that post / sub-category was posted under. I hope that makes a little more sense, again thanks a ton for the help!

Comment: @TheFragileMachine sorry didn't have time to update my answer, this code will do everything as you want

Answer (score 0):

I used this code for something similar on a project in the past, basically I needed to display content depend of the category, hope it works for you! Peace!

```
  <?php if (in_category('CATEGORY_1') ) : ?>
    WHATEVER YOU WANT TO DISPLAY
  <?php elseif (in_category('CATEGORY_2') ) : ?> 
    WHATEVER YOU WANT TO ECHO
  <?php elseif (in_category('CATEGORY_3') )  : ?>
    WHATEVER YOU WANT TO ECHO
  <?php else : ?>       

  WHATEVER ELSE :)

  <?php endif; ?>
```